# Whats wrong with this jQuery code (not POSTing data)

Tags: json, jquery

I'm just starting out with jQuery. I want to send JSON data to a server. I expect the response back as text/html.

This is my code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a id='json_1' href="#">Click Me!</a></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#json_1').click(function(){

            $.post("http://www.example.com", 
                   { "func": "getNameAndTime" }, 
                   function(data){alert(data); },
                   "json");
             }
         );
 });
</script>
</html>
```

When I click on the link, the alert box is displayed, showing 'Null'. Also, when I debug with FF, I can see in the console) that no data is being sent.

Can anyone spot what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Is the site on the same domain as the page? If not, that's probably the problem. Google 'same origin policy'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot perform Ajax requests to external sites due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: This was the cause of the problem. Thanks